# First eigenvalue of a fourth-order Schrödinger Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, calculus-of-variations

I am studying Roger Temam's *Infinite-Dimensional Dynamical Systems in Mechanics and Physics* (Second Edition) and am trying to work through section 4.1.2 - Eigenvalue of a Schrödinger Operator. For $\Omega = \left(-\frac{L}{2}, \frac{L}{2} \right)$, He defines the operator
$K_0: D(K_0)\subseteq \dot L^2\left(\Omega\right) \to \dot L^2\left(\Omega\right) $
as
$$ K_0 f = \nu D^4f -qf,$$
where $$q \in  
\left\{\ \phi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}): 
\phi(x+L) = \phi(x), \quad
\phi(-x) = \phi(x), \quad
\int_\Omega \phi dx = 0 \right\},$$
the space of infinitely differentiable, mean-free, even, and periodic functions,
and
$$ D(K_0) = \left\{f\in H^4(\Omega): 
f(x+L) = f(x), \quad
f(-x) = -f(x), \quad
\int_\Omega f dx = 0 
\right\},$$
the space periodic odd functions which are mean free and are four times weakly differentiable.
Temam also asserts that this operator is subject to boundary conditions
$$\partial_j u\left(-\frac{L}{2}, t \right) = \partial_j u\left(\frac{L}{2}, t \right),
\quad j = 0, 1,2,3.$$

Here is the part of this section that I am confused about. From here, Temam asserts that the first eigenvalue (first in the sense that it has the least value) is
$$ \lambda_1 = \inf_{f\in D(K_0)}\frac{(K_0f, f)}{\| f\|^2_{L^2}}.$$

Now, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $K_0$ with associated eigenfunction $g$ then we see that
$$
\frac{(K_0f, f)}{\| f\|^2_{L^2}} =  
\frac{(\lambda f, f)}{\| f\|^2_{L^2}} =  
\frac{\lambda ( f, f)}{\| f\|^2_{L^2}} = 
\lambda.
$$
So I understand that $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda $ for any eigenvalue $\lambda$. From here, I do not know how to proceed. How can one find an eigenfunction which has $\lambda_1$ as its eigenvalue?